ImportError: cannot import name 'get_formatted_location' from 'name_function'
I am doing a highschool python course and im having trouble importing a function from a different VS code tab using the import function.
First vscode tab:
from name_function import get_formatted_location

print("Say 'q' at any time to quit.")
while True:
    city = input("\nPlease Give me your city name: ")
    if city == 'q':
        break
    country = input("\nPlease give me your country name: ")
    if country == 'q':
        break

formatted_location = get_formatted_location(city, country)
print("\tFormatted location: " + formatted_location + '.') 

Second vscode tab:
def get_formatted_location(city, country):
    full_location = city + ' ' + country
    return full_location.title()

I made sure that everything was named correctly and there were no typos. Not sure what else the problem could be.

I'm going to guess that you forgot to save the second tab.

Also, saying "first tab" and "second tab" doesn't help us.  The names of those files would be much more helpful.

sorry, the names of the files are location.py and name_function.py

VSCode is only the file editor. It does not execute your code. Python does not now in which tabs the files are or even that you use VSCode. You can save your files in the same directory (not mandatory, but easier) and then import them by their file names, excluding the .py extension.

@IvanLoban You didn't save name_function.py after your last edit. The file exists, so it can be imported, but it does not contain a function called "get_formatted_location", because you haven't yet saved the current contents to disk.
